# ¿Cómo se pueden crear nuevos DIV'S?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo 12 div en el body, desde habitación 1 hasta la 12, la 12 es el ultimo y esta asi, esos 12 div tienen un boton que es disponible, al apretarlo cambia a ocupado, mantenimiento.

Este es el Javascript

```
function sig12(){

 var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ",);

for(i=0; i < array.length; i++){
if(document.getElementById('este12').value == array[i]){
var indice = (i + 1 == array.length) ? 0 : i + 1;
document.getElementById('este12').value = array[indice];
localStorage.setItem("estado12", array[indice]);
break;
}
}
}

window.onload=function()
{

if(localStorage.getItem("estado")!=null)
{
estado12 =localStorage.getItem("estado12");
document.getElementById('este12').value = estado12;
}
}
```

Este es el HTML donde esta el DIV:

```
<div class="span2">
<div class="well well-small">
<h4 >Habitación 12</h4>
<input id="este12" type="button" value=" Disponible " onclick="sig12()" />
<br>
<a href="habitacion1.php"><small>Alquilar</small></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Entonces ahora quiero un boton que se agreguen otros DIV de habitaciones, lo he hecho asi:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'></div>
<center><input id="crear1" type="button" value=" Añadir habitación " 
onclick="crear()" /></center>
```

Javascript:

```
var i = 0;

function crear() {

var array = new Array(" Disponible ", " Ocupado ", " Mantenimiento ");
if (i + 1 < array.length) {
i++;
crearDivs(array[i], array);
} else {
i = 0;
crearDivs(array[i], array);
}
}

function crearDivs(nameDiv, array) {
let divNuevo = document.createElement('div');
divNuevo.classList.add('divs');
divNuevo.innerHTML = nameDiv;

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(divNuevo);
document.getElementById('crear1').value = array[i];
}
```

Codigo css

```
.divs {
 float: left;
 width: 140px;
 height: 110px;
 background: white;
 margin-left: 20px;
 color: black;

 }
```

Al apretar el boton se crean los DIV que quiero y sale habitación 13,14,15,16 los que siguen, pero quiero saber sí al salir se le puede añadir el boton de disponible que tienen los otros 12 div primero que he creado, para que puedan mostrar el estado, no se si me entienden, espero que me puedan orientar o ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: por favor mejora el titulo de su pregunta, *ayuda con xxx* no es un buen titulo, lea [ask]

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz mejora tus ejemplos, talves los podes volver ejecutables con el sniper

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz creo que en tus ejemplos no hacen falta usar localStorage

Comment: ¿Cómo con Sniper? el localstorage lo utilizo por el boton disponible que cuando le doy click y cambia a Ocupado y me muevo a otra parte o apreto F5 se devuelve el valor disponible, entonces para guardarlo y no perderlo, que se queden los valores al ser cambiado.

Comment: ¿Dices que cuando pulsas añadir habitación aparecen habitación 13,14,15, etc.? Yo lo he probado y no salen nuevas habitaciones, al pulsar añadir habitación aparece "Ocupado", "Mantenimiento" o "disponible", uno de estos tres cada vez que pulso, y viendo tu código es lo que tienes, das al div el nombre de uno de esas 3 palabras y no el de habitación x. Lo que dices se puede hacer pero antes quiero entender mejor que has intentado.

Comment: Quizás has copiado el codigo mal. La primera parte es del DIV en si original que he creado, y la segunda parte es el DIV que se crea al apretar en añadir. Acá te dejo una imagen, estos son los div original https://prnt.sc/k79rcx y al dar click en añadir habitacion salen estos div https://prnt.sc/k79rrp quiero saber si el div que se crea se puede configurar para que salga con el mismo boton que tienen los otros